# Tmuxinator Panes Code Won't Work

Tags: terminal, tmux, tmuxinator

I'm copying example code directing into my .yml file, but I cannot get my panes to run any code:

```
# Will create panes, but will not open vim or echo
windows:
  - editor:
      layout: main-vertical
      panes:
        - vim
        - echo test
```

However, running code in its own window will work:

```
# Will open vim
windows:
  - vim
  - server: gulp watch
```

I'm looking running `tmuxinator version 0.6.7`.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

For anybody wandering the same:

Consider the following two issues:
https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator/issues/222
https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator/issues/214

For me 

`set-option -g base-index 1
set-window-option -g pane-base-index 1`

resolved the issue

Comment: It would be nice to describe the cause and the solution in more extend.

Comment: If you use a base-index other than the default, please be sure to also set the pane-base-index as mentioned at https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator#base-index

Answer (score 0):

I've just added the header to your first example and saved it to `~/.tmuxinator/teste.yml`,

```
# Will create panes, but will not open vim or echo
name: teste
root: ~/
windows:
  - editor:
      layout: main-vertical
      panes:
        - vim
        - echo test
```

, and it worked fine. Try reinstalling tmuxinator -- if that doesn't solve the problem you should try [tmuxinator issue tracker.](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator/issues)